# Nested Array Of JSON Looping in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the value of "id" of the below mentioned array of json but i'm not able to get the result because it is surrounded by two "[[" array braces, can anybody please help me out, Also im getting these array of JSON from another loop if the loop runs single time i'm getting single array brace "[" , if the loop runs multiple times i'm gettin "[[" braces...

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "id":"Task_1yett21"
         },
         "incoming":"SequenceFlow_112bxv0",
         "outgoing":"SequenceFlow_1gkdhq3"
      },
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "id":"Task_0i5lteb"
         },
         "incoming":"SequenceFlow_1gkdhq3",
         "outgoing":"SequenceFlow_1gjii2n"
      },
      {  
         "attributes":{  
            "id":"Task_1v37yfe"
         },
         "incoming":"SequenceFlow_1gjii2n",
         "outgoing":"SequenceFlow_0bygyft"
      }
   ]
]
```

I'm calling this function to get the JSON objects in the above array...

```
var getAllValuesOfKey = function (dataObj, queryKey) {
      var resultArr = [];
      if (!queryKey) {
          return resultArr;
      }

      function execute(dataObj, queryKey) {
          Object.keys(dataObj).forEach(function (key, index) {
              if (typeof dataObj[key] == 'object' && !(dataObj[key] instanceof Array)) {   
                  if (key == queryKey) {
                      resultArr.push(dataObj[key]);
                  }
                  execute(dataObj[key], queryKey);
              } else if (key == queryKey) {
                  resultArr.push(dataObj[key]);
              }
          });
      }
      execute(dataObj, queryKey);
      return resultArr;
  } 
  var searchKey = 'task';
  var result=getAllValuesOfKey(obj1, searchKey);
```

Comment: May you add what you have tried so far please?

Comment: Will you fix the other loop as well, so it always returns only one 'array brace'? That way the logic for getting the id values becomes very easy as well: `ary.map( item => item.attributes.id );`.

Comment: Please review the guidelines about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes a [mcve].

Comment: i've added the function where i'm getting the Array of JSON now above

Answer (score 0):

You can select the inner array in your loop with index 0 on the outer array, like this:

```
var myDoubleArray: any = [[{...}, {...}, {...}]];
for (let i = 0; i < myDoubleArray[0].length; i++) {
  console.log(myDoubleArray[0][i].attributes.id);
}
```

If the arrays are still in JSON format, you need to first parse them to JavaScript before you can loop through the data. This can be done with JSON.parse().

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [  
   [  
      {  
        "attributes":{  
           "id":"Task_1yett21"
        },
        "incoming":"SequenceFlow_112bxv0",
        "outgoing":"SequenceFlow_1gkdhq3"
     },
     {  
        "attributes":{  
           "id":"Task_0i5lteb"
        },
        "incoming":"SequenceFlow_1gkdhq3",
        "outgoing":"SequenceFlow_1gjii2n"
     },
     {  
        "attributes":{  
           "id":"Task_1v37yfe"
        },
        "incoming":"SequenceFlow_1gjii2n",
        "outgoing":"SequenceFlow_0bygyft"
     }
  ]
]

for (var i in arr[0]) {
  //arr[0][i].attributes.id will give you the id
  console.log(arr[0][i].attributes.id);
}
```